The Ancient Greeks: "running away from fate brings you directly into it". Can it be explained in secular terms?
Jews were not in agreement on the "predestiny":

There is some disagreement among scholars regarding the views on
predestination of first-century AD Judaism, out of which Christianity
came. Josephus wrote during the first century that the three main
Jewish sects differed on this question. He argued that the Essenes and
Pharisees argued that God's providence orders all human events, but
the Pharisees still maintained that people are able to choose between
right and wrong. He wrote that the Sadducees did not have a doctrine
of providence.

Christians confide "predestiny" only to the final fate of the soul - joining God:

The Catholic biblical commentator Brendan Byrne wrote that the
predestination mentioned in this passage should be interpreted as
applied to the Christian community corporately rather than
individuals. Another Catholic commentator, Joseph Fitzmyer, wrote that
this passage teaches that God has predestined the salvation of all
humans.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny#:~:text=Followers%20of%20Ancient%20Greek%20religion,a%20plan%20for%20every%20person.

​For Greeks, fate appears to be part of some natural order, not an active act of the Gods.

What about self-fulfilling prophecies, unintended consequences, psychological bias, confirmation bias or self-sabotage?

In ancient Greece, the threads of destiny were weaved by Moirai, the Fates, who were stationed even above gods. Not exactly a part of natural order translatable into secular terms. It is also unclear how natural order would take care of poetic justice that the Greek Fates dispensed (see Oedipus). But this reminds me the 'law' of time travel stories under Hawking's chronology protection. Travelers attempt to undo some 'bad' events, but trying to make them unhappen causes them to happen.

Scriptwriter vs role of God in a puppet show ?

Huge topic.
Generally, fate in ancient Greece was personilized by the Moires (fates). Initially there were three of them: 1: The dynamic that someone was born with. 2: Whatever happens during your life. 3: The third one, combined what could not be changed (1) with what comes in your life (2). The last process was described as "weaving". So we - as humans - have a responsibility and a choice to "weave" our lives from what cannot be changed and from what we can become of. So, in a sense, we are (or are materializing) the third (fate) the "weaver".
PS: The word Moira (fate) in greek means the part that one "takes" in his life from the total dispense.
